# SQL Distinct with If

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, distinct

I'm working with query that should return product code, or variation code instead if there is one connected and order them by modified attribute (to select the most recent modified products) found in the product table. There is my query:

```
SELECT IF(Length(variation_code) > 0, variation_code, prod_code) AS prod_code, 
       product.modified, 
       price 
FROM   product 
       LEFT JOIN variation_row 
              ON product.prod_code = variation_row.product_code 
WHERE  prod_code IN (SELECT prod_code 
                     FROM   product) 
       AND price > 0 
GROUP  BY prod_code 
ORDER  BY modified DESC 
LIMIT  6
```

The problem is, that if the same product is modified more than one time in a row, it might appear in the resultset more than one time.

I know that DISTINCT is used to get only values that differ from other, but I could not implement it into my query since IF is used to get prod_code.

Is there any way to modify my script so it returns same result but with distinct prod_codes?

Comment: I wonder if this code works at all because you group only by prod_code while neither of your select columns are included in the group by clause? Moreover: which purpose has "where prod_code in (select prod_code from product)? - you have already the product table in your first from clause: this seems to be redundant.

Comment: You're right about that "where prod_code IN (SELECT prod_code FROM product)", it is not needed. Query itself works fine since prod_code is one of the selected attributes (determined by IF clause).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- product.modified is a date
- product.modified together with product.prod_code are unique in product
- product.price is dependent on these two attributes
- you want to get the most recent modified entry per prod_code

then my suggestion is

```
    SELECT S.prod_code
         , S.modified
         , P.price
      FROM product P
     INNER JOIN
           (SELECT case
                     when Length(variation_code) > 0 then variation_code
                     else prod_code
                   end AS prod_code
                 , -- use the most recent modification
                   max(product.modified) as modified
              FROM product 
              LEFT JOIN 
                   variation_row 
                     ON product.prod_code = variation_row.product_code 
             WHERE product.price > 0 
             GROUP BY
                   case
                     when Length(variation_code) > 0 then variation_code
                     else prod_code
                   end 
           ) S
             on S.prod_code = P.prod_code
            and S.modified = P.modified;
```

This should work in Oracle, SQL Server and PostgresSQL. No idea if your database product (which one do you use?) supports this syntax?

### Edit after reading first two comments on the original answer

Would this help

```
select IF(Length(variation_code) > 0, variation_code, prod_code) AS prod_code
     , p.modified
     , p.price
  from product p
 inner join
       (select m.prod_code
             , max(m.modified) as modified
          from product m
         group by
               m.prod_code
       ) m
         on p.prod_code = m.prod_code
        and p.modified = m.modified
  left join
       variation_row v
         on v.product_code = p.prod_code
 order by
       p.modified desc
 limit 6;
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL, and this returned a resultset, but it seems it's not what I wanted. I try to make my task more understandable: I want to get latest modified products from product table. That would be a simple query to do. I have another table, variation_row that has variation_code/product_code -pairs (and other data which is out of scope of this task). If variation code exists, it should be used as prod_code. Otherwise the original prod_code from product code is used.

Comment: My query works well except the fact that it can return same prod_code (or variation code if used) more than once. I only need to get 6 latest modified products (and give variation_code as prod_code in resultset when exists) without duplicate product codes.

Comment: This gives the same result as my original query (had to add table reference in last parameter of if: 
"select IF(Length(variation_code) > 0, variation_code, m.prod_code)" since prod_code was ambiquous.

This does not help since the resultset still has same product multiple times if edited multiple times in row.

Comment: Ok, for a better help I would need the create table statements of both tables including a definition of their primary keys. If the last statement produces results with prod_code multiple times then (prod_code, modified) is not unique in product or (product_code) is not unique in variation_row.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a solution to this by myself. Do not know if this is the most effective way, but it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT prod_code FROM (SELECT IF(Length(variation_code) > 0, variation_code, prod_code) AS prod_code, 
       product.modified, 
       price 
FROM   product 
       LEFT JOIN variation_row 
              ON product.prod_code = variation_row.product_code 
WHERE  prod_code IN (SELECT prod_code 
                     FROM   product) 
       AND price > 0 
GROUP  BY prod_code 
ORDER  BY modified DESC) AS a LIMIT 6;
```

Thanks for trying to help me out with this!

Comment: Actually this still fails if i put modified and price in first select... can I make a query with distinct used only for one column?